# Как правильно вписать большую картинку в маленький блок целиком на CSS/SCSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, scss

В макете есть такой блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут две строки по 4 примера работ. Решил сделать на `flex` одну строку, чтоб по кнопке можно было догружать еще работы, но пока до JS не дошел. Нужно вписать картинку любого размера в квадрат.

Есть например картинка размером `740х740px` и мне надо целиком вписать ее в квадрат `480х480px`

В данном случае `object-fit` обрезает большую картинку примера работы, а я хочу уменьшить ее масштаб а не обрезать. Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вместе с `object-fit: cover;` надо `max-width : 100%` и `max-height: 100%` картинке назначить

Answer (score 5):

А почему `object-fit` не подошел, там же можно параметры на любой вкус выбрать?

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

Может задать картинку как background-image и задать размер с помощью background-size: cover

Comment: Аналогично можно использовать [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) для `<img>` или `<video>`